# Wordpress Custom Post Type Search

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, wordpress

I have a WP installation with a menu/restaurant theme that adds a custom post type for "food". "food" has a title and an excerpt field it doesn't have the regular "content" field. It seems that the default WP search facility will search in the title and the content fields but not the excerpt field.

I've tried several plugins to either add the content field to my custom post type or search in the excerpt field as well as the title field but I've had no success.

Am I missing something obvious?

Many Thanks

Comment: Not so much information in the question. Try the advanced custom field plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had a lot of success using [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin for altering WordPress's search functionality. You can have WordPress index custom fields, excerpts, and other things, and also add more or less weight to them in your search results.

In the excerpt's settings, check the box shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Option to index post excerpts]

and then click the bottom to rebuild your search index.

Comment: Brilliant I can confirm that plugin has worked a treat! Just what we were looking for! Thank you sir.